# How to scrape text between br tags

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to scrape a simple website `http://hosted.where2getit.com/sharpsiica/index.html?form=locator_search&sku=ARM355&addressline=53203&zip=53203`

I have tried the following code to scrape name and address:

```
import lxml.html as lh    
from selenium import webdriver    
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://hosted.where2getit.com/sharpsiica/index.html?form=locator_search&sku=ARM355&addressline=53203&zip=53203')

time.sleep(5)

content = browser.page_source

tree = lh.fromstring(content)

name=tree.xpath('//table[@id="collection_poi"]/tbody/tr/td[@align="left"]/a/text()')

address=tree.xpath('//table[@id="collection_poi"]/tbody/tr/td[@align="left"]/text()')

print(name,address)
```

I am getting names properly but for address I am getting too much unwanted data. I need the name and address only.

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need `lxml` if `selenium` itself can locate basically anything you want on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strip it -

```
address=[c.strip() for c in address]
```

Hope that helps.

But I am just wondering,
Why would you extract an entire list of addresses and Names?
Wouldn't you want to do something like,

```
import lxml.html as lh
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://hosted.where2getit.com/sharpsiica/index.html?form=locator_search&sku=ARM355&addressline=53203&zip=53203')
time.sleep(5)
content = browser.page_source
tree = lh.fromstring(content)

for tr in tree.xpath('//*[@id="collection_poi"]//tr'):
    name=tr.xpath('.//*[@class="store_name"]//text()')
    name=[c.strip() for c in name]
    address=tr.xpath('.//*[@align="left"]//text()')
    address=[c.strip() for c in address]
    print(name,address)
```

You may even want to remove empty elements from the obtained list,

```
address=filter(None, address)
print address
```

Hope that helps :-)